# Data mapping : from "any" class to a generic key value map (C++)

Tags: c++, serialization, adapter, key-value

For logging purposes, I would like to adapt various classes (for this reason I'd like a generic approach) to a key value dictionary : this could be seen as "key value serialization".

Let's assume the keys are pre-defined and that, depending on the input class we do want to adapt, each value may correspond to a specific attribute.
Values can always be encapsulated into an std::string.

This would be my approach :

Create an adapter class which can be dumped into the database

```
#include <keys.h> // enum with possible keys, defining type Key_t

namespace generic
{
    class Adapter
    {
        public:
            Adapter();
            virtual ~Adapter();
            virtual void init() = 0;

        private:
            std::map<Key_t, std::string> _data;
    }
}
```

For every possible client, specialize the adapter class in its namespace, supposing it is friend with any client's specific business object model (to access attributes easily), and that it receives the instances of such models via const references in its constructor

e.g.

```
#include <generic/Adapter.h>

#include <client1/bom1.h>
#include <client1/bom2.h>
...
#include <client1/bomN.h>

namespace client1
{
    class Adapter : public generic::Adapter
    {
        public:
            Adapter(const Bom1& bom1,
                    const Bom2& bom2,
                    const BomN& bomN)
            : _bom1(bom1), _bom2(bom2), _bomN(bomN)
            {}

            void init()
            {
                // Explicit data mapping in here
                 _map[NAME] = _bom1._name;
                 _map[TITLE] = _bom2._title;
                 ....
                 ....
            }

        private:
            Bom1 _bom1;
            Bom2 _bom2;
            BomN _bomN;
      }
}
```

What do you think about this approach ?
Is there a more generic way of achieving this in c++ ?
What would have been your design ?

Thanks!

**Update**

When a new client is implemented the logging engine shouldn't change: that is why the adapting logic should be distributed on client side rather than being implemented in the core of the logging engine.
The logging engine would be updated only if new keys are required (this would probably imply a database structural change).

Comment: you can just use a templated log function ...

Comment: I was thinking about this apporach too, but I have lots of clients, and for each client a lot of data to map : I'd like to avoid centralizing all the data mapping into a single big templated function which would need to be specialized for every single client (each has its own different BOMs); I'd prefer to distribute mapping on client side.

Answer (score 0):

I would have stored serialized strings for both keys and values.
[Here](http://code.google.com/p/libglim/source/browse/trunk/ldb.hpp) I'm using the `ldbSerialize` method which uses boost serialization by default and can be easily specialized without creating a new class. For every new type of the key one would simply add a new specalization:

```
template <> inline void ldbSerialize<Key32> (string& bytes, const Key32& key) {
  bytes += key.whatever();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be mere serialization in this case ? I might be missing something, but, the point is I need to serialize different structures into something which is somehow a static and pre-defined data map. This approach would do for the serialization part, but what about adapting ?

Comment: Ok, tailored to your use case this might look like `template <> inline void logMe<Key32> (std::map<Key_t, std::string>& data, const Key32& key) {data[NAME] = key._name;}`; the point is to have a default serialization method and specialize it for new clients.

Comment: What would be the advantage of this against simple "logMe" function overloading ?

Comment: The advantage (IMO) is that you can have a default logMe without deriving your clients from some base class. It is less intrusive and easier to implement for the client author. (And in my case the default function uses Boost serialization). But since you wrote above that you'd "like to avoid centralizing all the data mapping into a single big templated function" perhaps your initial approach is best, although I don't see from your example how the big "init" method would differ from a big specialized "logMe" function.

Comment: And you can have templated helper functions, e.g. logUsualFields, which you can call from the logMe specializations. That way you can decentralize the serialization. IMO it is cleaner than messing with inheritance.